# React js- npm install not working in a github project

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-start, recoiljs

I have a project from github and it has the recoil function. I'm trying `npm install` to run npm but it's not working:

[image]

Then I tried `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, and got

```
61 vulnerabilities (4 low, 5 moderate, 39 high, 13 critical)
```

If I write `npm start` I got

```
Debugger attached.

> tgp-core-api@0.1.0 start
> PORT=3006 react-scripts start

'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Answer (score 0):

It still says your debugger attached when you run "npm install".

Try to stop debugging (Debug > Stop Debugging or Shift+F5).

Comment: thanks for your help, i stoped debugging but i'm still facing the same error!

Answer (score 0):

well i found out that inside my package.json i had :

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "Port=3006 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

so i deleted Port=3006, with that i got:

```
 "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
```

and it worked!